# How to access Docker container shell and mount volumes using Portainer?

Tags: docker, portainer

I have installed Docker CE on Ubuntu 18.04 and I am using Portainer UI to make deploying containers easily.

I am still a beginner in Docker, I have followed many tutorials but I am still clueless about Mounting volumes of running containers.

For example;

I installed Nginx using official image provided in the Portainer UI, it is running well and shows NGINX default page.

Now I want to add my HTML files and edit NGINX configuration but I cannot find any files on my local hard drive.

I know that Docker uses volumes to store encrypted data..

How do I mount the files of a running container onto my Ubuntu machine and edit configuration/html files on the go

I like the idea of Docker, running apps in containers.

I was able to deploy same containers in Heroku but mounting volumes, editing files, I have no clue about it.

Sorry if this a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

[Nginx configuration and content folders](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/deployment-guides/setting-up-nginx-demo-environment/#configuring-nginx-open-source-as-a-web-server) are */etc/nginx* and */usr/share/nginx/html*.

The most simple way is [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). When run container just need to define a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container:

```sh
docker run -d \ 
    --name nginx_mount \ 
    -v /var/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \
    -v /var/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx:ro 
    nginx:latest
```

Where */var/www* and */var/nginx/conf* are folders on the host machine.

---

[Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/) allows to configure volumes through UI (open Container -> Duplicate/Edit)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Especially if you are starting a very good place to learn about the images you are using is actually their official pages on Docker hub.

Open https://hub.docker.com/ and search for "nginx". The verified official page comes first so click on that. That page will answer all you questions here so I suggest you go through it. There you can also see how the actual Dockerfile is made up and you can learn a lot from that as well.

If you still have questions after I'll be happy to assist.